# Automatically add addon from app.json, heroku.yml or other config

Tags: heroku

I would like to provide a button from github to directly deploy an app.
Its a go application which serves some website.

Now for persistent data it requires an addon "Heroku Postgres".

I tried defining a heroku.yml with:

```yaml
setup:
  addons:
    - plan: heroku-postgresql
```

I tried app.json with:

```json
{
  "addons": ["heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"]
}
```

But it does nothing at all, it never adds the addon. I know I can add it manually through the website or CLI, but I want a fully automatic way - if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look something like this

```json
 "addons": [
    {
      "plan": "heroku-postgresql",
      "options": {
        "version": "12"
    }
  }
]
```

[Example app.json from heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#example-app-json)

Comment: So it also works without specifiying the version, `"addons": [{"plan": "heroku-postgresql","options": {}}]`

Comment: "options" is a optional property. It should work just with `"addons": [{"plan": "heroku-postgresql}]`. Also check this [Changelog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/924) for more information.